# Avoid null field after storage in IsolatedStorageSettings

Tags: c#, silverlight, isolatedstorage, datacontract

On Silverlight, I got a `DataContract` like this:

```
[DataContract]
class Operation
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;

    public readonly OperationManager Manager = new OperationManager();
}
```

I do not want to store or serialize *Manager*, which is why it's not a `DataMember`. *Manager* is not-null when doing `new Operation()`. But when I retrieve it from `IsolatedStorageSettings`, I get a null *Manager*:

```
// operation.Manager is not null
var Settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
Settings["key"] = operation;
Settings.Save();
operation = (Operation)Settings["key"];
// operation.Manager is null
```

Is there a way to automatically re-initialize *Manager* to something new when it is being unserialized by `IsolatedStorageSettings`? I tried to set it in constructor, but constructor is not called when going through `IsolatedStorageSettings`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to initialize something coming from `IsolatedStorageSettings` is either `[OnDeserializing]` or `[OnDeserialized]` (can't use `.ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` as not available on Silverlight).

```
[DataContract]
class Operation
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;

    OperationManager _manager = new OperationManager();
    public OperationManager Manager { get { return _manager; } }

    [OnDeserializing]
#if WP7
    internal
#endif
    void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext c)
    {
        _manager = new OperationManager();
    }
}
```

`[OnDeserializing]` and `[OnDeserialized]` must be internal on Windows Phone 7, and private on Visual Studio 2013. -_-

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Silverlight or IsolatedStorageSettings so I don't know if there are any special tricks, but a simple solution would be to use a property and instantiate the `OperationManager` in it if necessary.

```
private OperationManager manager; // no longer readonly

public OperationManager Manager
{
    get
    {
        if (manager == null) manager = new OperationManager();
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Comment: But then it's only not non-null on a `get`. If I don't `get` at some point, the *OperationManager* is not instantiated. And I need an instance of it to perform automatic background tasks. I was looking for a way to initialize it as soon as `Settings["key"]` is accessed for example.

Comment: @Cœur If you need it only for that then why is it in the Operation class? Do you need one OperationManager for each Operation instance?

Comment: Yes. I have simplified my example, but I need an instance for each instance.

Comment: @Cœur But does it have to be a field of the Operation class? If it wasn't you could just create a manager object when you deserialize the operation. But it looks like you simplified your problem a bit too much. Sorry if this answer doesn't really help, but I'll let it stay because it might show others what you are *not* looking for.